# How to install ImageMagick for PHP5.3/5.4 on Windows 8 x64

Tags: php, windows, imagemagick

I need install ImageMagick for PHP 5.4.7 on Windows.

How do I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step by step:**

1. Download the [binary version](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) for Windows Install you binary version.
2. Test you install in CMD

   1. Execute `convert` in `CMD`.
3. If this work, the intall is success.
4. Now, download Imagemagick [DLL for PHP](http://valokuva.org/%7Emikko/imagick-php54-php53.tgz)
5. Open imagemagick-php54-php53.tgz
6. In Explorer, go to PHP extension folder

   1. PHP: `C:\php\ext\`
   2. XAMP: `C:\xampp\php\ext\`
7. Copy `TS` or `NTS` DLL's (`php_imagick_(nts|ts).dll`) from imagemagick-php54-php53.tgz:

   1. For PHP 5.3

      1. imagick-php54-php53.tgz\imagick\php53
   2. For PHP 5.4

      1. imagick-php54-php53.tgz\imagick\php54
8. Paste in you PHP Extension folder.
9. In explorer, edit you php.ini
10. Add the follow line:

**if you use TS**

```
extension=php_imagick_ts.dll
```

**If you use NTS**

```
extension=php_imagick_nts.dll
```

Now, restart you apache/ngnex server.

> IMPORTANT!

> If you have a error to start apache/ngnex with the message
> **Unable to find CORE_RL_Wand.dll something something**.

1. Open imagemagick-php54-php53.tgz
2. Go to `imagick-php54-php53.tgz\imagick\ImageMagick-x.x.x-vcx\`
3. In my case `imagick-php54-php53.tgz\imagick\ImageMagick-6.8.0-vc9`
4. In explorer go to:
5. Win 32: `C:\Windows\System32\`
6. Win 64: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\`
7. Uncompress all DLL's from `imagick-php54-php53.tgz\imagick\ImageMagick-x.x.x-vcx\`
8. And start you apache/ngnex server.